# Move file from laravel server to Nuxt server

Tags: laravel, file, server, nuxt.js

I have two separate project, laravel and nuxt;
i want to, when i upload file from the laravel, it'll be stored on static folder of the nuxt project. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you'll need to send your file upload to a CI that will inject it into the Nuxt project, and rebuild the whole Nuxt app.

Also, remember that `static` is not bundled via Webpack.
Meaning that it will be shipped raw: if it's uploaded while not being properly optimized, it'll be shipped as is (would be better suited into an `/assets` directory but still >> **build time** for the whole project required here).
Even hosting it on your Laravel server is more worth at this point.

TLDR: it's not worth to send it to Nuxt's `static` directory.
I recommend hosting it on a CDN or alike.